# iMacros 10.3 works different on different machines

Tags: imacros

I’ve run into an iMacros situation that I have never encountered before and was wondering if anyone has ever come across anything like this.  I developed a macro for an application our company developed.  It basically enters a location, a start time, and a run time.  It runs good on my machine.  I sent it to the person who requested it and it doesn’t work for her.  She is getting this error:

Error -1300: Cannot find HTML element of type "INPUT:TEXT" with attribute(s) "NAME:WRKD_DOCK_NAME_label".. Line 3: TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:page_form ATTR=NAME:WRKD_DOCK_NAME_label CONTENT=LOSANGELES

I’ve checked her machine for the following items to confirm that it is the same as mine (they are):

(1) Tab settings in Internet Explorer

(2) iMacros Add-ons:
a.  iMacros Browser Helper Object (enabled)
b.  iMacros for IE (enabled)

(3) iMacros version 10.3.27.5830

(4) 32 bit machine

(5) Operating System: Windows 7 Enterprise

(6)     Confirmed that LOSANGELES is a valid value

All of these are the same.  Something has to be different.  Let me know if you have any suggestions.  Thanks………